# Changing color of a toolbar dynamically in Vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, data-binding, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I want to change the color of my toolbar dynamically in Vuetify (Please note I know there are similar posts on this website but none of them use Vue)

I used `v-bind:style` to do so, but it doesn't work!
This is my template and its respective script:

```
<v-toolbar
  flat
  fixed
  app
  v-bind:style="{ color: dynamic }"
  light
  scroll-off-screen
>

...

data: () => ({
 dynamic: 'black'
})
```

Comment: did you try backgroundColor?

Comment: @seyet may I ask what causes the color to change?

Comment: @Perogy yes, it didn't work. However tony19 has given me a working solution

Comment: @DjSh I was experimenting by manually changing the 'dynamic' value but I want to change it by clicking a button in the future. thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `v-toolbar` has a `color` property that controls its background color. You could bind `dynamic` to that property instead of a style binding:

```
<v-toolbar :color="dynamic" ...>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    dynamic: 'black'
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.7/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.7/dist/vuetify.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons">

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-toolbar dark :color="dynamic">
      <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Title</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
        <v-btn flat>Link One</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Link Two</v-btn>
        <v-btn flat>Link Three</v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>
    </v-toolbar>
  </v-app>
</div>
```